# Help compiling multiple .ino file code with code! (I'm not sure what to name this)

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

Ok, so i'm trying to make [This Project](http://www.instructables.com/id/AbHhGD-the-Arduino-Based-Hand-held-Gaming-Device/?ALLSTEPS) and the code comes all in different .ino files but in the video its all in one program. So how do I compile all of the code onto the arduino? (By the way the code is on step 5 in a .zip file) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the .ino files is likely the main code file.  Name the enclosing folder with the name of the .ino file, then compile it as normal.

In this case, AbHhGD.ino is the main file, and its folder should be named 'AbHhGD'

The comments indicate there are missing libraries you likely need to install.

Comment: Ok so I just rename the folder that has everything in it to AbHhGD and then compile abHhGD.ino?